# Rails params parsing, escaping needed?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm currently using Jquery to serialize() a form, which contains a textarea, and POST it to Rails.

This works successfully in most cases, unless the textarea contains a line in quotes, on its own. If such a line exists Rails parses the contents between the quotes of that line as the params variable rather than the entire contents of the field.

*For Example: take the task[description] of the following POST Request, sent to rails 2.3.8 via Jquery Post*

**FireBug: POST Parameters**

```
authenticity_token  r0uu4QQ9e73aEsSKl2LJRIWap1BSQWMKRaieCOwHEpg=
task[description]   line1 
                    "line2" 
                    "line3"
                    line4
task[due_date]  
task[project_id]    1
task[responsible_user_id]   nobody
task[title] Parse Bug
```

**Firebug: POST Source**

```
       authenticity_token=r0uu4QQ9e73aEsSKl2LJRIWap1BSQWMKRaieCOwHEpg%3D&
       task%5Bproject_id%5D=1&task%5Bresponsible_user_id%5D=nobody&
       task%5Bdue_date%5D=&task%5Btitle%5D=Parse+Bug&
       task%5Bdescription%5D=line1%0A%22line2%22%0A%22line3%22%0Aline4
```

After rails parses the request params[:task][:description] gets the value of "line2" rather than the entire text block. (line1 "line2" "line3" line4)... see below

**Rails development log**

```
     Processing TasksController#create (for 127.0.0.1 at 2010-07-26 17:05:06) [POST]
     Parameters: {"action"=>"create", "authenticity_token"=>"r0uu4QQ9e73aEsSKl2LJRIWap1BSQWMKRaieCOwHEpg=", 
     "task"=>{"title"=>"Parse Bug", "project_id"=>"1", "due_date"=>"", 
              "description"=>"line2", "responsible_user_id"=>"nobody"}, "controller"=>"tasks"}
```

It seems that Rails parses from the **POST source** anything between two **%0A%22** as the content of the variable rather than everything after the **=**

The quotes are escaped as %22 but should I be escaping them differently?

Much Thanks! *If my description is confusing please ask me to clarify any part of it.*

**Updated**

Here's the relative Jquery used:

```
$('#new-item').find('.submit').live('click', function(){
    var form = $(this).closest('form');
    $.post(form.attr("action"), form.serialize(), null, "script");
    return false;
});

$.ajaxSetup({
   'beforeSend':function(xhr) {xhr.setRequestHeader("Accept", "text/javascript")}
})
```

Comment: To add some more clarification, this only happens if an entire line is in quotes. If just part of the line is in quotes Rails parses things appropriately. 

If 2 lines are completely in quotes (as in the example above, "line3"). It will take the 1st line in quotes as the params hash value.

I see several votes and stars, are others also experiencing this?

Comment: If others are like me the stars are people adding it to favourites so they can see the answer.

Comment: Could you edit the question and add the jquery code you are using to do the post please.

Comment: Hi Steve, I updated my original post with the jQuery used. It's very similar to what you posted below.

Answer (score 1):

I've followed the instructions in [Ryan Bates Railscast 136](http://railscasts.com/episodes/136-jquery) and created a minimal application using a subset of your model.

This is all working fine for me. Rails 2.3.5 Ruby 1.8.7 OS/X

**FIREBUG: Post**

**Parameters**

```
authenticity_token  7JSQYKGEsteve8Emm5ZrdstOEgvvSJCD6Quxl588g5M=
task[description]   line1 "line2" "line3" line4
task[responsible_user]  steve
task[title] Test 2 quoted
```

**Source**

```
authenticity_token=7JSQYKGEsteve8Emm5ZrdstOEgvvSJCD6Quxl588g5M%3D&task%5B
description%5D=line1%0A%22line2%22%0A%22line3%22%0Aline4&task%5B
responsible_user%5D=steve&task%5Btitle%5D=Test+2+quoted
```

**Rails Development log**

```
Parameters: {
  "authenticity_token"=>"7JSQYKGEhgfIY8Emm5ZrdstOEgvvSJCD6Quxl588g5M=",
  "task"=>{"title"=>"Test 2 quoted",
  "description"=>"line1\n\"line2\"\n\"line3\"\nline4", 
  "responsible_user"=>"steve"}
}
```

The relevant code from the rails application is as follows :-

**application.js**

```
// public/javascripts/application.js
jQuery.ajaxSetup({ 
  'beforeSend': function(xhr) {xhr.setRequestHeader("Accept", "text/javascript")}
})

jQuery.fn.submitWithAjax = function() {
  this.submit(function() {
    $.post(this.action, $(this).serialize(), null, "script");
    return false;
  })
  return this;
};

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#new_task").submitWithAjax();
})
```

**app/views/tasks/create.js.erb**

```
// views/tasks/create.js.erb
$("#new_task").before('<div id="flash_notice">
  <%=escape_javascript(flash.delete(:notice)) %></div>');
$("#tasks_count").html("<%= pluralize(Task.count, 'Task') %>");
$("#new_task")[0].reset();
```

**app/views/tasks/create.js.erb**

```
<% form_for @task do |f| %>
  <p id="tasks_count">
    <%= pluralize(Task.count, 'Task') %>
  </p>
  <%= f.error_messages %>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :description %><br />
    <%= f.text_area :description %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :responsible_user %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :responsible_user %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :title %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :title %>
  </p>
  <p><%= f.submit "Submit" %></p>
<% end %>
```

The obvious difference is the format of the paramaters within Firebug. Mine all appear on one line but the encoded source looks fine to me. (I am using Firebug Lite but I wouldn't see that making a difference)

Comment: Hi Steve, I appreciate your help. Seems unusual to me that you aren't able to replicate the problem, I'm creating a lightweight dummy app now to run more tests.